# CloudQueueMessage - retry mechanism

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I using Azure Storage Queues for handle my items processing flow. Tasks are getting into the queue, Being processed by the background server and removed from the queue.

In some cases, the processing of some task is failed (due to environmental variables - which can't be expected). In this case, I want to retry the execution of the task again. If this time the processing was fine, everything is good - just remove it from queue. Otherwise, remove it from queue and write some message to the log.

So, I'm looking for some mechanism to add meta-data to CloudQueueMessage item. I'm thought about a new meta-data called 'retries'. Which will be a counter. But I'm don't see any option to add meta-data to a queue item.

Another option is to wrap my item with Wrapper class that will add 'retries' property. After dequeue the item from the queue, re-insert it with modified 'retries' value. This should work but, not an elegant solution.

What is your recommendations?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn589788.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to. When the item has been picked up by your worker role from the queue it's actually still there but marked as not visible. By default it's invisible for 30seconds. You can set the visibility using "visibilityTimeout" though. The item stays in the queue until you remove it.

Comment: This is nice approach. But, how I can be sure that this is the second time I handle this specific item? Be aware that after the second try, I want to remove it from queue. Otherwise, this will be infinite loop.

Comment: I found the solution. I can use the "Message.DequeueCount" for understanding how many times this message has been dequeued. Thank you very much.